# stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: command-line

When i added

```
stty intr ^X
```

to my ~/.zshrc file it is always showing stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device on startup.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `stty` should really only be used with interactive shells. The simplest option is to prefix the `stty` statement with a conditional so that it is only executed in an interactive shell.

Here is one way to do it:

```
[ "$PS1" ] && stty intr '^C'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still getting the same error. Is there any other way to do the same? I want to bound interrupt to ctrl+x

Comment: @A_HiddenDonut the zsh equivalent would be `[[ -o interactive ]]` I think - see for example [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600541/65304). (To be pedantic, it's the equivalent of bash `[[ $- == *i* ]]` which is a more direct way of testing for bash shell interactivity.)